# TFS 2018 - application version management

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

In TFS 2018, There's a need to manage versions for application that is managed as a team under a team project.

Normally such versions could be managed as iterations, each of which having its sprint children. However, it so happens that there are cases where there's an overlapping between Start Date / End Date of these versions. In such cases, while working on a current version, part of the team already works on the next version in parallel, and TFS shows only one iteration as current in the backlog screen, although in this case there are two current versions...

A solution can be to add dedicated field for VersionNo, in which the team will assign work item to version. However, since version number can be arbitrary number, it will not be reasonably possible to bind it to some predefined manageable list.

Another solution might be to use AreaPath to manage these versions, because area path is based on manageable tree definition, but that could mean using AreaPath for a purpose not intended to in TFS. Since we would like to keep compatibility with future TFS updates, is this solution ok in this manner ? Can u suggest another solution ? Kindly note TFS Release mng mechanism seems to apply to the distribution of the code but not to the versioning of it as needed above.